# Spring boot @Transactional and Persistence Context

Tags: spring-boot, jpa, spring-data-jpa

I use JPA in my springboot. As far as I know, springboot containers use a transactional scope persistence context strategy by default.

#### The code I've put together is based on this.

- Put the repository class @Transactional annotation

```
@Repository
@Transactional
public class EntityRepository {
    private final EntityManager em;

    public EntityRepository(EntityManager em) {
        this.em = em;
    }

    public Entity save(Entity entity) {
        em.persist(entity);
        return entity;
    }

    public Optional<Entity> findOne(Long id) {
        return Optional.ofNullable(em.find(entityClass, id));
    }
```

- I used two functions of that class back-to-back in the service layer.

```
@Service
@RequiredArgsConstructor
public class EntityService {

    private final EntityRepository entityRepository;

    public Entity postEntity(Integer userId, EntityCreateRequest entityRequest) {
        var result = lostsRepository.save(EntityMapper.INSTANCE.toEntity(lostRequest));
        
        ... //another code

        var getEntity = lostsRepository.findOne(result.getId());

        return getEntity;
    }
```

What I'm expecting is to have two transactions, each using a different persistence context.
But if that's the case, then when using the `findOne` function,
you should send a new query that doesn't come from the primary cache in the persistence context.
But if you look at the actual query that Hibernate sends, it doesn't send a new query from `findOne` to get the value, it gets a cached value from somewhere.

I've tried debugging this and that, but it seems to be using the same persistence context, because when I `clear()` inside the `save` function, it sends a new query to get it.

As I understand it, we are using 1 persistence contact per transaction, why did this happen? If anyone knows, please answer.

Answer (score 1):

@Transcational by iteself means REQUIRES propogation by default which means
you ar in the same transaction.

I don't recommend using @Transactional in the repository layer. It is better to
put it in the service layer.

the idea here to develop service method as atomic function.

Answer (score 0):

if you want to have two transactions, then you should use extended persistence context type

```
@PersistenceContext(type = PersistenceContextType.EXTENDED)
private EntityManager entityManager;
```

because default type of persistence context is PersistenceContextType.TRANSACTION. for more information you can take a look at [jpa hibernate persistence context](https://www.baeldung.com/jpa-hibernate-persistence-context)